# LWC third party library DOM changes not applied

Tags: lightning-web-components, dom, highcharts

I'm trying to use Highcharts charting library in LWC. I have an empty `div` element, `<div class="chart-target" lwc:dom="manual"></div>` targeted by the chart. This works well.

The problem is that when the window is resized, the chart is not automatically reflown as it should be.

I've added a resize event listener to the `window` in the `renderedCallback`, which is being correctly called, as evidenced by console outputs. In the event listener, I've manually invoked the `reflow` method on the chart. This should reflow the chart but seems to have no effect.

However, if I capture the console output of the variable pointing to a chart as a global variable in my browser's console and call `reflow` on it (`temp1.reflow()`), the chart is correctly reflown.

This reminds me of other JS libraries where a change done outside the library should be manually applied (for example, `scope.$apply` in Angular).

What mechanism of LWC am I missing that would support such interactions?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same using chart.ref.setSize(some dynamic width, some dynamic height, false) for angular 5. i thought it's also work in LWC

```
let chartMonthly = new Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: '0',
                    //type: 'column',
                    // width: 508,
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    reflow: true


                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
......
});
```

so here i defined chartMonthly as a variable
Then i am going to set the size of chart using below code

````
reflowchart(event) {        
        setTimeout(() => {   
            var width = Some dynamic width 
            this.chartMonthly.ref.setSize(width, 400, false);
        }
```, 300);
    }
````